# proper way to display and filter an object in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

Right now I have data being returned from an API that is structured like the following

`{_ids: "690506", _addresses: "987394", _bids: "709395", _sids: "384130"}`

```
<ul>
    {{Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(DataCounts._ids)}}
     Location Records
</ul>
<ul>
  <v-icon>{{ mdiArch }}</v-icon>
    {{Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(DataCounts._addresses)}}
     Location Records
</ul>
<ul>
  <v-icon>{{ mdiArch }}</v-icon>
    {{Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(DataCounts._bids)}}
     Location Records
</ul>
```

etc.....

Is there a more compartmentalized way to structure this in the UI so when/if the API changes I do not have to go and check 30 lines of code to make sure it works.

Comment: can I get feedback on why this was down voted please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vue filters

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

```
// create global filter
const mySpecialFormat = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
Vue.filter('numberFormatEn', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return mySpecialFormat.format(value.toString())
})

// then use it somewhere
{{ DataCounts._ids | numberFormatEn }}
```

or something along those lines

---

EDIT: Or did you mean how to simplify `Object(k,v) -> html(ul)`

in that case something like

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

```
<ul v-for="(value,key) in DataCounts" :key="some-key">
  <v-icon v-if="...">{{ mdiArch }}</v-icon>
  {{ value | numberFormatEn }}
  Location Records
</ul>
```